# How can I modify the DroidGap.class file from phonegap-1.0.0.jar archive in eclipse?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, class, cordova

I am really very new on android development.
I have made 2-3 apps , those running on my android device already.

Last few days I am facing a stupid problem.

The problem is , creating the app fullscreen for every device. I have read phone gaps wiki
and tried with specific way. But I failed everytime.
When I'm trying to open the DroidGap.class from my Android eclipse project explorer , I got a error. that, "DroidGap.class has no source attached". (after build the phonegap.jar)

Please help me....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Use the [AppLaud Eclipse Plugin for PhoneGap Android](http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/34483744/PhoneGap-Eclipse-PlugIn-for-Android)
- Download and unzip the PhoneGap sources from [GitHub](https://github.com/callback/callback-android)
- In the AppLaud wizard, select "Enter path to installed PhoneGap"
- Enter the directory path to the unzipped sources from GitHub
- Now you will be able to modify and debug the sources that comprise phonegap.jar

Caveat: I'm the creator of the AppLaud Plugin

Comment: Really thanks for your help. But I want to know, after installing plugin if I click to DroidGap.class then I should see the source code?

Comment: When you click on DroidGap.class, you should see an "Attach Source..." button in the edit pane. Click that button and then navigate to your github source and select the framework/src folder

Comment: But, if you use AppLaud and build with the sources from GitHub, you'll have DroidGap.java instead of DroidGap.class and won't need to do the Attach Source... step

Comment: Also, Attach Source is enough to just see the source code. To modify it, you need to change DroidGap.java, not DroidGap.class

Comment: Hey boss, I have done everything but how can I rebuild the project? because I was modify the DroidGap.java and make it source for DroidGap.class and I could saw the modification but when I am run the android application it was like before. So how could I rebuild the project?

Comment: Eclipse does automatic builds. You should be able to Run As Android application and run with the changes

Comment: I did your steps but when I run, somehow it worked like before. thanks

Comment: I told that I want only full screen... I modified main activity java file and DroidGap.class as the phonegap wiki told... But I don't know, that do I need to modify something on AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: What do you mean by full screen? Please add a link to the wiki page you are referencing. OR - perhaps you should add another question specifically about full screen, since your title question is now answered here.

Comment: I am sorry for that, [PhoneGap wiki](http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/22863272/Hiding%20the%20status%20bar%20at%20the%20top%20in%20Android) is the. I think you will understand the best.

Comment: Ohh.. thank you for your time. finally I done it. you are a genius. Keep helping people... Most of them give you massive feedback.

Answer (score 1):

1. first you need to add phonegap.jar to your project
2. you need to add phone gap plugin to your eclipse

Comment: I have added the phonegap.jar in to the libs/ dir.

Answer (score 0):

fullscreen?
If you want modify DroidGap.class dowload source code from github and rebuild phonegap.

Rebulid instruction here: https://github.com/callback/callback-android/blob/master/README.md

Comment: Yes! download droidgap.java from github but how can I rebuild the project and how would I add the class into the project? please explain.

Comment: You must download all source and rebuild library, then overwrite library in your project

Comment: Please explain with eclipse setps. I told that , I'm very new on android and phonegap